# How to insert javascript safely into database and take them back as it is?

Tags: javascript, database, wordpress

I'm making a WordPress Advertisement Management Plugin. Need the user to enter Google AdSense and other ad code into the database.

I checked the other solution like the `mysql_real_escape_string()` and `base64_encode()` & `base64_decode()`. But they are not doing the desired result.

I'm using a simple form like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108351/22728):

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <textarea name="ad_code"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

To insert into the db:

```
<?php
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
        global $wpdb;
            $table = $wpdb->my_table = $wpdb->prefix . "my_table";
            $data = array(
                'ad_code'    => $_POST['ad_code']
            );
            $format = array(
                '%s'
            );
            $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );
            if($success) echo 'data saved';
        }
?>
```

With the aforementioned code, I tried with:

```
$data = array(
    'ad_code'    => mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['ad_code'] )
);
```

and

```
$data = array(
    'ad_code'    => base64_encode( mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['ad_code'] ) )
);
```

and

```
$data = array(
    'ad_code'    => base64_encode( $_POST['ad_code'] )
);
```

The first two attempt completely failed me. But using only the `base64_encode()` is doing a good job encoding the texts into code and inserting into the db, but when I'm trying with `<?php echo "<pre>" . base64_decode( $the_ad_query->ad_code ) . "</pre>"; ?>` in my db query, it's not showing anything.

Instead of JavaScript, I tried with simple string like "This is the code", it's doing just fine. But I failed with JavaScript code.

My google adsense code is like this:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- my ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-32131313131312317"
     data-ad-slot="8657754785"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

How can I proceed then? Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows. `Both $data columns and $data values should be "raw" (neither should be SQL escaped).` There is no need to escape anything. Why are you using base64 encoding? Wouldn't it be much easier to just store the JS raw in the database?

Comment: @user555 Right you are. But how can I escape such code field so that any malicious script can't get in, and can't get echoed? I think even with the encode-decode process as I answered below have the chance of inserting malicious scripting code into the database and into the site too. How can I proceed into such extent?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam **What**? Base64 encoding has nothing to do with preventing malicious scripts, especially since you're just decoding it and echoing it on display.

Comment: There is no build in function to do what you want. By base64 encoding your code your only changing the way you store the information inside the database. As soon as you decode the data it will be the same as before the encoding, any malicious code will still be present. The easiest way would be to just ask the user for the adsense code, store it and then rebuild the code on page load.

Comment: I don't get it, are you trying to output the code so the user can read it, in a `<pre>` block? Or are you actually trying to output the code *as code*, so it will be executed?

Comment: I want the code to work as an ad. With `<pre>` tag I's just checking in dev. env. :) Now, with/without base64 encode-decode I can enter the script into db and can get back as it is and my ad is echoing too. Just need to put a checker so that malicious script can't get in, in case.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the database, or encoding, or *anything* to do with how the script is stored. You're going to have to prompt them for their GA account number, and store only that much of it. Then you can output the number and your own version of the GA code.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam You will have to build some kind of whitelist/blacklist filter. Way to much work if you ask me. **Just ask for the needed values, store them in the db and then build the code either directly or on each page load.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Got a solution. Don't know whether it's the right way or not:

When inserting:

```
$data = array(
    'ad_code'    => base64_encode( trim( $_POST['ad_code'] ) )
);
```

When echoing:

```
<?php echo "<pre>" . stripslashes( base64_decode( $the_ad_query->ad_code ) ) . "</pre>"; ?>
```

Comment: `base64_decode` isn't the tool for this job. `$wbdb` will already escape the data, there is no need to do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same adsense code, and just swap out the publisher ID. Then you wouldn't have to worry about storing js.. Just store their publisher ID.

Comment: The question title isn't saying it's only adsense based. There could be any kind of ad_provider code. And this solution is already provided by @meagar in the comment of the Question. Btw thank you.